# Trying to create HIMAGELIST, what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to create an `HIMAGELIST` for the list view. It actually needs to consist of file icons.

Here's the code I have:

```
HIMAGELIST imageList = ImageList_Create(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON),
                                          GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON),
                                          ILC_MASK, 1, 1);

HICON ico = reinterpret_cast<HICON>(LoadImage(0,IDI_APPLICATION,
                                                IMAGE_ICON,0,0,LR_SHARED));
ImageList_AddIcon(imageList, ico);

ListView_SetImageList(listView, imageList, LVSIL_SMALL);
```

The list view with three elements now has three application items.

However when I try to add another icon (`IDI_HAND` in this case), I still get the same 3 icons.

Another problem I have is that I can't fetch the actual file icons I need:

```
SHFILEINFO sfi;
SHGetFileInfo (L"C:\\test.txt", NULL, &sfi, sizeof (sfi), SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX | SHGFI_SMALLICON);
ImageList_AddIcon(imageList, sfi.hIcon);
```

This results in empty icons, not the `txt` icons I want.

I've been struggling with this for ever, and I greatly appreciate your help here.

*UPDATE*

I'm using sample code I found on the Internet to fill the list view (obviously that's not what I want):

```
UINT columnMask = LVCF_TEXT|LVCF_FMT|LVCF_SUBITEM|LVCF_WIDTH;
LVCOLUMN lc[] = {
{ columnMask, 0, 150, L"Text...",0, 0,0,0 },
{ columnMask, LVCFMT_CENTER, 70, L"Number",0, 1,0,0 },
{ columnMask, 0, 100, L"Whatever",0, 2,0,0 },
};

ListView_InsertColumn(listView, 0, &lc[0]);
ListView_InsertColumn(listView, 1, &lc[1]);
ListView_InsertColumn(listView, 2, &lc[2]);

UINT itemMask = LVIF_TEXT;
LVITEM li[] = {
   { itemMask, 0,0, 0,0, L"...for the first item!",0, 0,0,0,0,0,0 },
   { itemMask, 0,1, 0,0, L"1",0, 0,0,0,0,0,0 },
   { itemMask, 0,2, 0,0, L"14 bucks",0, 0,0,0,0,0,0 },
   { itemMask, 1,0, 0,0, L"...for the second item!",0, 0,0,0,0,0,0 },
   { itemMask, 1,1, 0,0, L"24",0, 0,0,0,0,0,0 },
   { itemMask, 1,2, 0,0, L"2 suns",0, 0,0,0,0,0,0 },
   { itemMask, 2,0, 0,0, L"...for the second item!",0, 0,0,0,0,0,0 },
   { itemMask, 2,1, 0,0, L"24",0, 0,0,0,0,0,0 },
   { itemMask, 2,2, 0,0, L"2 suns",0, 0,0,0,0,0,0 },
   { itemMask, 3,0, 0,0, L"...for the second item!",0, 0,0,0,0,0,0 },
   { itemMask, 3,1, 0,0, L"24",0, 0,0,0,0,0,0 },
   { itemMask, 3,2, 0,0, L"2 suns",0, 0,0,0,0,0,0 },
};

// setting an icon like this doesn't work
li[0].iImage = sfi.iIcon;

ListView_InsertItem(listView, &li[0]);
ListView_SetItem(listView, &li[1]);
ListView_SetItem(listView, &li[2]);

ListView_InsertItem(listView, &li[3]);
ListView_SetItem(listView, &li[4]);
ListView_SetItem(listView, &li[5]);

ListView_InsertItem(listView, &li[6]);
ListView_SetItem(listView, &li[7]);
ListView_SetItem(listView, &li[8]);
```

Comment: (1) Please provide more info about what you mean by "I still get the same 3 icons." Nowhere in your code do you actually try to use any of the icons you added. (2) If you pass `SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX` then you're saying "I don't want the `hIcon`. I'm only interested in the `iIcon`." Since you want the `hIcon`, you shouldn't pass that flag.

Comment: @Raymond, I've updated my question. I'm adding the items to the listview via `ListView_InsertItem`. And I'm setting the image list with `ListView_SetImageList(listView, imageList, LVSIL_SMALL);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `iImage` member of `LVICON` is the index of the icon in the imagelist you passed to `ListView_SetImageList`. You are passing the index of the icon in the system imagelist, but the imagelist you passed to `ListView_SetImageList` is your private imagelist. Either

1. Use `ListView_SetImageList` to associate the imagelist with your private imagelist, and set the `iImage` to the index in your private imagelist (the return value from `ImageList_AddIcon`)
2. Use `ListView_SetImageList` to associate the imagelist with the system imagelist, and set the `iImage` to the index in the system imagelist.

Comment: Did you mean "iImage member of LVITEM"?

Comment: And I'm sorry, I got really confused. Once I call `ListView_SetImageList`, I assign my image list to the list view. There's only one image in it, and it appears in all items of the list view. Adding a second image does nothing. I tried to set iImage values of the LVITEMs to the return values from `ImageList_AddIcon`, but again nothing. All I get is the first image added to the list multiplied by the amount of rows.

Comment: You didn't set LVIF_IMAGE to say that you wanted to set the image.

Answer (score 2):

For your second problem, try passing just the .extension, in your case pass .txt as the first param, and these flags: SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX or SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES or SHGFI_SMALLICON or SHGFI_ICON and on return, sfi.hIcon should contain the handle of the txt file icon

Without SHGFI_ICON, SHGetFileInfo is just filling in sfi.iIcon which is the index of the icon in the system imagelist, by adding SHGFI_ICON, SHGetFileInfo will also fill in sfi.hIcon which is what you want.

How are you adding the listview items?  Show the code where you fill in the LVITEM structure.

Comment: Thanks for the extension tip! Now I actually get the icon I need. I've  added code to the question.